# unknown attribute Rails on import CSV uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the error ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in ProductsController#import, while trying to import a large csv file.

The migration is done and the table is created.

When i try to process the file I get,

unknown attribute 'CO_NO' for Product.

Extracted source (around line #14):

Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :co_no, :parcel_id, :file_t, :asmt_yr
  require 'csv'

  def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

  product_hash = row.to_hash # exclude the price field
  product = Product.where(id: product_hash["id"])

  if product.count == 1
    product.first.update_attributes(product_hash)
  else
    Product.create!(product_hash)
    end # end if !product.nil?
     end # end CSV.foreach
      end # end self.import(file)
       end # end class
```

controller:

```
classProductsController<ApplicationController
  def index
    @products=Product.all
  end

def import
  Product.import(params[:file])
  redirect_toroot_url,notice:"Productsimported."
end
 end
```

csv header:

```
co_no,parcel_id,file_t,asmnt_yr,bas_strt plus many more
27,"0000009500001010","R",2014
```

irb output:

```
Product.all
NameError: uninitialized constant Product
from (irb):2
from /Users/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `Product.all` should be executed on `rails console` instead of irb

Comment: Your code will be a lot easier to read if you indent it properly. You're also missing quite a lot of white space between words - is this really the code as it is in your app?

Comment: On the console, i get the same message as above. As far as white space, I used a text editor to add and remove spaces, so I could paste 4 spaces, so the code in the app is formatted differently. i'll edit now.

Comment: Ok in console, i get  2.1.3 :001 > Product.all
  Product Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products`
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Comment: Please try with attr_accessible as its rails.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch without trying out the code, but the error message you are showing...

```
unknown attribute 'CO_NO' for Product.
```

indicates an input attribute that is "CO_NO", but you've declared "co_no".  Since Ruby is case sensitive for variable names is probably failing to find attribute "CO_NO" (as opposed to "co_no").

Comment: In database table it is co_no, in the model it is co_no, in the csv file it is co_no. any clues?

Answer (score 0):

By adding quotes around the cvs header, I was able to get past the error.

"co_no","parcel_id","file_t","asmnt_yr","bas_strt"

Also, I discovered coming from Rails 3 to Rails 4 that attr_accessor  is now handled in the controller. After these 2 tweaks the data imported correctly